# Handle StringIndexOutOfBoundsException for string

Tags: java

```
try {
    string = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
} catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe){
    System.out.println("invalid input");
}
```

I am trying to use this code for handling exception for the string that i am getting from a text file. But i get an error saying try to change the actual string declaration to character. I am not sure how to handle this ?

Comment: What type is `string`?

Comment: `charAt()` returns a `char`, not a `String`. Are you really hoping to set `string` to the first character of the line? Or are you just hoping to check if it has a length > 0?

Comment: @DanGetz i am hoping if that the string that i am obtaining from an a text file is > 0. For instance the text file has a string "programming" and it thows an indexoutofboundexception saying that String index out of range: 11

Comment: @JonAbraham: Please make your question clearer. Currently your title talks about one error, whereas the body of your question talks about another - without actually quoting the exact error, which is very confusing. It's *also* confusing because you haven't given a short but complete program, so we've had to guess at the type of `string`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe title is what i am aiming for catch stringoutofboundexception but i believe someone already pointed that strings from text file are of type character so i am trying to work on that to see if i declare text that i obtain from text file as characters and not string.

Comment: @JonAbraham: No, strings are strings - but you're asking for the first *character* of each line, which is a single *character*. Do you understand the difference between the `char` type and the `String` type? If you don't, I would *strongly* suggest you hit the books before going any further - if you keep going while confused about that, you're really not going to make much progress. And why would you want to *handle* that exception rather than avoiding it? (Please bear in mind that if you refer to an exception in your title, readers will assume that's an exception you're actually seeing.)

Comment: @JonSkeet appreciate your advice but i am pretty clear on the difference between character and string. Let's put it like that - I don't know what i was getting from a text file i.e. whether it was character or string but now that Eran has commented below i am very much clear on what i was getting from text file.

Comment: @JonAbraham: With respect, if you understood the difference between `char` and `String`, you would have understood that you *didn't* need to read the file character by character, but using `charAt` *does* return a single character. The line "strings from text file are of type character" strongly suggests confusion. To put it another way: did you look at the return type of `charAt` before posting the question? It would be good to use this experience as a learning opportunity to work out how you could have diagnosed the problem for yourself, to help for next time.

Comment: @JonSkeet appreciated sir, i would take your advice and would look further into the difference between string and char and how scan.nextline() works ? BTW i am student it's  a learning experience for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But i get an error saying try to change the actual string declaration to character.

`scan.nextLine().charAt(0)` is a `char` so if `string` is a `String` (as implied by the compilation error you got), you can't assign a char to it.

If you need just the first character of the input line, you should store it in a `char` variable.

```
char first;
try {
    first = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
} catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe){
    System.out.println("invalid input");
}
```

Of course you can avoid the need to catch this exception if you test the length of the String before getting its first character :

```
char first;
String line = scan.nextLine();
if (line.length() > 0)
    first = line.charAt(0);
else
    System.out.println("invalid input");
```

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't actually answer the question - given that the OP is getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, presumably `string` is (bizarrely) a `char` already.

Comment: @JonSkeet Based on the error the OP got, this absolutely answers the question. The OP wrote code to handle StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, but failed to get this code to pass compilation.

Comment: Ah - I was looking at the error in the *title* rather than the one in the body. It really doesn't help when there are contradictory errors in the question :( Have edited my answer accordingly. (Your answer now deals with the immediate compilation error, but not the operation the OP is really trying to achieve.)

Answer (score 2):

Your *compilation* error is because [`String.charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) returns a `char`, not a `String`. They're different types - and you need to be *very* clear about the difference between them. You *could* just change the variable to a `char` variable, renaming it at the same time - but that's a really bad way of checking whether or not a string is empty. Deliberately provoking an exception like this when you can just test it directly is a bad idea - any time you find yourself catching a specific `RuntimeException`, you should ask yourself whether there's a better way of avoiding it.

You should use `String.isEmpty()` or `String.length()` before trying to take the first character of it. For example:

```
String line = scan.nextLine();
if (line.isEmpty()) { // Or line.length() == 0
    // Whatever you want to do for invalid input.
} else {
    char firstChar = line.charAt(0);
    // Use firstChar
}
```

Of course, if you don't actually *need* the first character, and you were just trying to detect empty strings, you can just use the first part of this, without the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

The method charAt() as the name indicates returns character. So the compilation error was because you are trying to assign a character to the variable (in your case, string) of type String.

If your objective is to retrieve the next line from scanner object and check it's 0th index for character to look for exception, you can do something like below:

```
String string = null;
..
char c;
string = scan.nextLine();
try {
    c = string.charAt(0);
} catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe) {
    //Exception handling
}
```

This way, you can continue to use the string that was read using nextLine() prior to the exception happened due to the call of charAt().

Hope this helps.